# SUM Function in VBA - not hard coding rows and columns

Tags: excel

How do I use the lastRow variable in the sum function in vba? After I count the number of words in each row until the last row, I would like to add up the individual totals from each row into an overall total column but I do not want to hard code the range into the sum function in vba? Is there another way?

Example:

```
Column:   A   B   C   D   E   F  
NRow 1:   2   3   4   5   6   7  
NRow 2:   3   4   5   6   7   8  
Total 3:  5   7   9   11  13  15
```

Want to avoid `SUM(R[-2]C:R[-1]C)`? I would like `SUM(R[lastRow]C:R[-1]C)` or something that would function in the same way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that there is always data in `column A` then to find the last row you could do the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub addSums()

Dim lstRow As Integer
With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp).Row

    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Column
        .Cells(lstRow + 1, j) = "=SUM(R[-" & lstRow - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)"
        .Cells(lstRow + 1, j).Font.Bold = True
    Next j

End With

End Sub
```

Seems to work ok on the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this which

1. Sets the usedrange on the active sheet from `A1` to the last used cell in column `F`
2. Goes to the first cell below this range `Cells(rng1.Cells(1).Row + rng1.Rows.Count, 1)`, resizes to the amount of columns in the range of interest (6 in this case)
3. Enters the forumula `"=SUM(R[-" & rng1.Rows.Count & "]C:R[-1]C)"` where `rng1.Rows.Count` gives the first row dynamically

**code**

```
Sub GetRange()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
Cells(rng1.Cells(1).Row + rng1.Rows.Count, 1).Resize(1, rng1.Columns.Count).Value = "=SUM(R[-" & rng1.Rows.Count & "]C:R[-1]C)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

If your source data is coming frm an external source, the appropriate mechanism is:

- Create a Named Data Range around the input table;
- Set the inut table to automatically resize on refresh; and
- Then use the Named Data Range in your functions.